# How to use sed or awk for editing really long Java class

Tags: java, awk, sed, decorator

I am implementing a `Decorator` pattern for the class which has a lot of methods. I created this `Decorator` class and just put all the methods that should be here. 
Now I have a class with 2000 lines where every part like:

```
@Override
public String getCapadCode()
{
    return null;
}
```

should be replaced with:

```
@Override
public String getCapadCode()
{
    return origin.getCapadCode();
}
```

Is it possible to somehow automate this process with sed or awk?

Comment: Why do you have a class with 400 methods anyway? That's a bit of a red flag in and of itself.

Comment: Have you consider other options like lombok? https://projectlombok.org/features/Delegate.html

Comment: I really don't think it can be easily done, maybe write some script (in perl for instance) instead, anyway are you sure it's a good idea? Have you ever heard about SOLID and the Single Responsibility Principle?

Comment: @all I intentionally put this question to `sed` category instead of `java`, because the design is approved here and hasn't been changed in 8 years and probably will never be changed. I know that this code has code smells, but still, the question is how to edit such a big file

Comment: I think this would be far easier in something like awk (or perl). `$1 == "public" {clname = $3} ...etc...`

Comment: search replace in your IDE, with some regexp

Comment: This code doesn't have *smells*, it *stinks to high heaven*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use search and replace with regular expression like this:

search:
`get(.*)\(\)\R\{\R    return null;\R\}`

replace:
`get$1\(\)\R\{\R    return origin\.$1;\R\}`

I use Eclipse Find/Replace for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of perl:

```
perl -pe '
    m{public .* (.+)\(} and $methodName = $1; 
    s{(?<=return )null;}{origin.$methodName();};
' File.java
```

If you are satisfied it works, call it with `perl -i -pe` to write-in-place.

Comment: Using perl for this. That's wild :)

Answer (score 0):

Use at your own risk:

```
$ awk '/^public/{name=$3} /return/{sub(/null/,"origin."name)} 1' file
@Override
public String getCapadCode()
{
    return origin.getCapadCode();
}
```

Comment: This is the result of the run return origin.GcrRecordWithRoundedAmounts

Comment: I don't know what that means but are you saying the script doesn't do what you want? When you run the script I posted on the sample input you provided it produces the output you said you wanted as you can see in my answer. If there's some other format of input that you haven't included in your example then of course you should not expect the script to know what you want to do with that format. If you want a completely robust solution that will work for any input then you need a parser for whatever language you input files are written in.